# Regex URL Expression match

Tags: regex

I am making an expression for validation the url in a right format. Expression works but i want if the url go beyond .com then it should not match. I mean expression starts from HTTPS/HTTP ---> .com.
It should not go beyond .com like https://www.google.com/abcdefgh...

Regex:

```
 "/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some minor changes and adding the lookahead `(?=.*?\.com$)`, your working regex would look like this:

`\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?www\.(?=.*?\.com$)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]`

`(?=.*?\.com$)` validates that the regex will match the url only if it has `.com` in the end

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VgU1Hx/1)